# Hodge isometries between K3 surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

I'm starting to study K3 surfaces and i have seen many examples of them as Kummer surfaces, smooth quartic in $\mathbb{P}^3$, double covering of $\mathbb{P}^2$ ramified over a smooth sextic...

But no book i have read (i'm referring principally to huybrechts' notes) seems to deal the examples of hodge isometries between K3 surfaces.

Do you have or do you know where i could find some enlightening examples?

Comment: Are you looking for Hodge isometries between the $H^2$ or just between the transcendental lattices? (If the former, any Hodge isometry can be converted to an isomorphism of K3 after composing by a Weyl group element.)

Comment: no actually i'm looking for isometries between the $H^2$. Also i'd prefer to find them not induced from isomorphisms between the surfaces

Comment: you might want to have a look at Morrison's 1987 paper "Isogenies between Algebraic Surfaces with Geometric Genus One".